# Hibernate updates child entity with null and not removes, how to force it?

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I have Playlist entity that owns collection of clips annotated with CascadeType.All. Although, in fact, it is bidirectional relationship, I defined it unidirectional to avoid exccessive cascades. So Clip has playlistId integer property and not reference to playlist. Clip is defined as part of playlist, so it can't exist without it. Therefore 'Playlist_ID' column in DB is defined not-null and getPlayListId() too. I read, that if I remove item from collection, cascade considers it as remove of relationship, but not entity removal. In my case it is a problem, since cascade tries to set Playlist_ID column to null and causes constraint violation.

I want the code: 
playlist.getClips().remove(0); dao.update(playlist)

will delete the clip. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: can u show us the entityes and the mapping

Answer (score 1):

You should use orphanRemoval:

```
@Entity
public class Playlist {

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Clip> clips;

}
```

Comment: In my understanding, orphanRemoval means, that if I remove playlist and I have clip in it, that is not linked to any other playlists, the clip will be removed. In my case I don't remove the playlist. My workflow is: clip removed from collection, playlist that holds the collection saved. In this case hibernate tries to detach clip from playlist without deleting it, and I want that cascade will delete the clip.

Comment: OrphanRemoval is used when the relationship between Playlist and a clip is removed. Removing whole Playlist is of course one use case when that happends. Removing a clip from a list is another - in both cases the orphanRemoval will cause deletion of the clip. From the [JPA documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html): _(Optional) Whether to apply the remove operation to entities that have been removed from the relationship and to cascade the remove operation to those entities._

Comment: It doesn't work. When I add 'orphanRemoval' it adds delete action to batch, as needed, but it also adds update action before and it still fails due to constraint violation

Answer (score 1):

If you use the old HBM notation of `inverse=true`, it will work the way that you want it to work. If you are using Hibernate Annotations, the new way of saying `inverse=true` is to use `mappedBy` on the parent side.

Add a Playlist member field to your Clip object with the proper mappings. If you have a `@JoinColumn` annotation on your Playlist entity, comment it out, and at your `@OneToMany` annotation, add a property of `mappedBy="whateverYourPlaylistVariableIsCalled"`

That will tell Hibernate NOT to update, and ONLY to delete when you break the relationship.